# How to encrypt decrypt image in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, encryption

Hye. I'm new in oracle. Currently, I've create a package for encrypt and decrypt the text in the database. Now i want to encrypt and decrypt the image that has been stored in my database.

This is the package that i use for encrypt and decrypt the text.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE enc_dec
 AS
   FUNCTION encrypt (p_plainText VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC;
   FUNCTION decrypt (p_encryptedText RAW) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC;
 END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY enc_dec
AS
     encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_DES
                                 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                                 + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
 /*
   ENCRYPT_DES is the encryption algorithem. Data Encryption Standard. Block cipher. 
   Uses key length of 56 bits.
   CHAIN_CBC Cipher Block Chaining. Plaintext is XORed with the previous ciphertext 
   block before it is encrypted.
   PAD_PKCS5 Provides padding which complies with the PKCS #5: Password-Based 
   Cryptography Standard 
 */
 encryption_key     RAW (32) := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('MyEncryptionKey');
 -- The encryption key for DES algorithem, should be 8 bytes or more. s3curiTKEY4App

 FUNCTION encrypt (p_plainText VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC
 IS
    encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
 BEGIN
    encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
    (
       src => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_plainText),
       typ => encryption_type,
       key => encryption_key
    );
   RETURN encrypted_raw;
 END encrypt;
 FUNCTION decrypt (p_encryptedText RAW) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
 IS
    decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
 BEGIN
    decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
    (
        src => p_encryptedText,
        typ => encryption_type,
        key => encryption_key
    );
    RETURN (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (decrypted_raw));
 END decrypt;
```

END;
/

So what is the function to encrypt and decrypt the image? can you show me the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image is a binary file. Since those files tend to be larger than 4k bytes, you would use a `BLOB` datatype most likely. In this case, you can use the procedure [`DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_crypto.htm#i1003081) that works with BLOBs.